# Access multidimensional array without multiple loops

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, key-value

Let's say I have an array formatted like so:

```
   $data = array(
        'variables' => array(
            '823h9fhs9df38h4f8h' => array(
                'name' => 'Foo',
                'value' => 'green'
            ),
            'sdfj93248fhfhf88rh' => array(
                'name' => 'Bar',
                'value' => 'red'
            )
        )
    );
```

Say I wanted to access the name & values of each array in the variables array. Surely you can access it just looping over the main variables array and not looping over each individual item array? Something like so?

```
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $name = $data['variables'][0]['name'];
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Comment: there is no `$data['variables'][0]`, if you don't know the keys then you need to do a loop inside a loop, if you already know the keys you don't

Comment: Seeing as the key is stored in $k, why can I not use: `$data['variables'][$key]['name']`

Comment: thats the key for the outer array

Comment: FYI: multiple foreach loops for a multidimensional array is very common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
foreach ($data['variables'] as $k => $v) {
  $name = $v['name'];
}
```

Comment: well if i knew that was what you where asking ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

create a new array containing just the names..

```
$new_arr = array_column($data['variables'],'name' );
echo $new_arr[0].'<br/>';
echo $new_arr[1].'<br/>';
```